# Type Conflict While Writing NUnit Tests

Tags: c#, nunit, warnings

I am getting the below warning in VS Code while writing Unit Tests with NUnit:

*The type 'MyClass' in 'MyProject.cs' conflicts with the imported type 'MyClass' in 'MyProject, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null'. Using the type defined in 'Myproject\Tests\MyClass.cs'. (CS0436) [Tests]*

These are the steps I took so far:

1. Navigated to my desired folder for all C# projects (e.g. `E:\MyCSharpProjects`).
2. Created a new C# Console Project via `dotnet new console -o MyProject`.
3. Wrote some code.
4. Ran the following command once: `dotnet new -i NUnit3.DotNetNew.Template`. I assume this installs NUnit project templates.
5. Created a new folder inside `MyProject`'s root folder called `Tests`.
6. Navigated inside the new `Tests` folder and ran the following commands:

   `dotnet new nunit`

   `dotnet add reference ../MyProject.csproj`
7. Installed the `NUnit` package via NuGet on `MyProject.csproj`.
8. Wrote some test code.

**NOTE 1:** For both `MyProject.csproj` and `Tests.csproj`, I set `TargetFramework` to `netcoreapp2.2` because I do not want to use 3.0 just yet.

**NOTE 2:** To avoid build errors, I stop Assembly Information generation by adding the following entries under `PropertyGroup` to both my .csproj files:

```
<GenerateAssemblyInformationalVersionAttribute>false</GenerateAssemblyInformationalVersionAttribute>    
<GenerateAssemblyConfigurationAttribute>false</GenerateAssemblyConfigurationAttribute>    
<GenerateAssemblyFileVersionAttribute>false</GenerateAssemblyFileVersionAttribute>        
<GenerateAssemblyCompanyAttribute>false</GenerateAssemblyCompanyAttribute>
<GenerateAssemblyProductAttribute>false</GenerateAssemblyProductAttribute>    
<GenerateAssemblyVersionAttribute>false</GenerateAssemblyVersionAttribute>
<GenerateAssemblyTitleAttribute>false</GenerateAssemblyTitleAttribute>
```

**NOTE 3:** Below is my MyProject.csproj file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
    <GenerateAssemblyInformationalVersionAttribute>false</GenerateAssemblyInformationalVersionAttribute>
    <GenerateAssemblyConfigurationAttribute>false</GenerateAssemblyConfigurationAttribute>
    <GenerateAssemblyFileVersionAttribute>false</GenerateAssemblyFileVersionAttribute>
    <GenerateAssemblyCompanyAttribute>false</GenerateAssemblyCompanyAttribute>
    <GenerateAssemblyProductAttribute>false</GenerateAssemblyProductAttribute>
    <GenerateAssemblyVersionAttribute>false</GenerateAssemblyVersionAttribute>
    <GenerateAssemblyTitleAttribute>false</GenerateAssemblyTitleAttribute>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="NUnit" Version="*"/>
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

**NOTE 4:** Below is my Tests.csproj file:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp2.2</TargetFramework>
    <IsPackable>false</IsPackable>
    <GenerateAssemblyInformationalVersionAttribute>false</GenerateAssemblyInformationalVersionAttribute>    
    <GenerateAssemblyConfigurationAttribute>false</GenerateAssemblyConfigurationAttribute>    
    <GenerateAssemblyFileVersionAttribute>false</GenerateAssemblyFileVersionAttribute>        
    <GenerateAssemblyCompanyAttribute>false</GenerateAssemblyCompanyAttribute>
    <GenerateAssemblyProductAttribute>false</GenerateAssemblyProductAttribute>    
    <GenerateAssemblyVersionAttribute>false</GenerateAssemblyVersionAttribute>
    <GenerateAssemblyTitleAttribute>false</GenerateAssemblyTitleAttribute>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="nunit" Version="*" />
    <PackageReference Include="NUnit3TestAdapter" Version="*" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.NET.Test.Sdk" Version="*" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <ItemGroup>    
    <ProjectReference Include="..\StudentService.csproj" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

The warning started showing up once I tried referencing a class inside my `Tests` project called `MyClass`. This class is only declared inside my `Tests` project and does not have any name conflicts with `MyProject`. I have however read that this might be caused by `Tests.csproj` referencing `MyProject.csproj` while being located inside `MyProject`.

My C# project is structured as follows:

```
E:\MyCSharpProjects
    MyProject
        MyProject.csproj
        <MyProject code files>
        Tests
            Tests.csproj
            <Tests code files>
```

My questions are:

1. Is having a test project that references my actual project the only way to use NUnit?
2. Is there a way to only have 1 C# project that has NUnit tests inside it, similar to Java and JUnit?
3. I am keeping my test project inside my actual project so they are always together. Is this the standard practice? And if not, what is?
4. How do I get rid of said warning? I'm don't want to ignore it because I don't like having warnings in my code.

**UPDATE:** In case my questions are too broad to answer, a link on standards on how to write NUnit tests from beginning to end would also be useful.

---

**SUMMARY:** [desmondgc's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8959165/desmondgc) answer worked! Turns out all I needed to do was add a `.sln` file to my project and everything worked perfectly! No warnings, and no need to disable Assembly Information generation at all!

Many thanks to everyone who helped!

Comment: 1. How else you want to test something that you don´t reference? 2. That completeley depends on your own implementation. If you want you can write everything into a single assembly. 3. too opinion-based. I won´t recommend it, tough. 4. Don´t know. Having said this all your question is far too broad.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please see [Unit testing C# with NUnit and .NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/testing/unit-testing-with-nunit) from the .NET Core Guide. They propose a directory structure like this:

```
/unit-testing-using-nunit
    unit-testing-using-nunit.sln
    /PrimeService
        Source Files
        PrimeService.csproj
    /PrimeService.Tests
        Test Source Files
        PrimeService.Tests.csproj
```

This is generally what I've used on all my projects, as well.

Regarding the warning, it sounds like you've defined the same class and namespace in both projects. The namespace should usually mirror the directory structure, so if you have a project called MyProject, a test project called MyProject.Tests and a class called MyClass in each, I would expect to find the fully-qualified names `MyProject.MyClass` and `MyProject.Tests.MyClass`. Even better, call the test class `MyClassTests` or something like this.

Comment: Indeed, my test codes are already mirroring the directory structure (MyProject.Tests and so on), which is why the warning is extra puzzling. I have a feeling the reason you don't get any warnings is because you are using a `.sln` inside VS Studio instead of having multiple `.csproj` files inside VS Code. Perhaps VS Code is not suited for C# development after all?

Comment: I will try following the instructions on the link you provided and create a `.sln` file this time. Hopefully this makes the warning go away. :)

Comment: Hey, it worked! Turns out I was on the right track -- I was just missing a proper `.sln` file to hold my `.csproj` files together. Many thanks for the link!